# How to input ctrl+z in c4droid

Tags: c++

Basically, does anyone know how to input end of file, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, or <kbd>F6</kbd> in c4droid? C4droid is an android C++ compiler, but I don't know how to input that :(.
I tried literally writing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> but that of course doesn't help.

Help please.

Comment: Did you check `Ctrl+D` ?

Comment: EOF is not a real character; what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @CarlNorum OP is trying [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19433464/1870232) probably from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19433614/1870232) reply

Comment: Exactly. There's no real special keyboard for this type of command. And simply writing CTRL+D only takes it as an input for the string.

Comment: I presume you want to trigger end-of-file for a program compiled under C4droid, not for C4droid itself. A comment on a deleted answer suggests that the volume-down key acts as Control, so Volume-Down+D seems to be the answer. You might also consider installing the [Hacker's Keyboard app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard&hl=en), which provides an actual Control key. [Termux](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux&hl=en) is another nice desktop-like environment for Android.

Answer (score 0):

Copying information from the comments on an answer that's been deleted, apparently in the C4droid environment you can use the Volume-Down key as a Control key. Typing `d` while holding the Volume-Down key should send a <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> character to your application, which should trigger an end-of-file condition.

As an alternative consider installing the [Hacker's Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard&hl=en) Android app; it gives you a desktop-style keyboard including an actual Control key.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an answer to a 4 year old question, but if you define your character as a type int, then using Ctrl-D for EOF will work.

Answer (score -1):

Put `^Z` instead of <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>
Try it

Comment: Based on the comments on a deleted answer (which you probably can't see), this is unlikely to be correct. `^Z` is a common way to represent Ctrl-Z as text, but typing `6` followed by `Z` is unlikely to do any good. Even if it did, Ctrl-Z suspends the current process; it doesn't trigger end-of-file. The correct answer appears to be Ctrl-D, where the Volume-Down button acts as a Control key within the C4droid environment.